# regexp to match string with (comma-separated) number at start and to split into number and rest?

Tags: javascript, regex

Given a string such as:

`23,234,456 first second third`

How can I split string this into two parts, where part 1 contains the number *at the beginning* and part 2 contains the rest---but only if the string STARTS with a number, and the number can be comma-separated or not?  In other words, I want two results: `23,234,456` and `first second third`.  If there's a number in that string that isn't part of the first number then it should be in the second result.

My best stab at this so far, to grab the number at the beginning, is something like this:

`^[0-9]+(,[0-9]{3})*`

Which seems to grab a comma-separated or non-comma-separated number that starts the line.  However, when I run this in the Javascript console I get not only the full number, but also a match on just the last 3 digits with their preceeding `,`.  (e.g. `23,234,456` and `,456`).

As for getting the rest into another var I'm having trouble.  I tried working with `\b`, etc., but I think I must be missing something fundamental about grabbing the rest of the line.

I'm doing this in Javascript in case it matters.

More examples of what to match and what not to match.

`2 one two three` should return `2` and `one two three`

`2345 one two three` should return `2345` and `one two three`

`2 one 2 three` should return `2` and `one 2 three`

`2,234 one two 3,000` should return `2,234` and `one two 3,000`

The space between parts 1 and two could be included in the beginning of part 2.

Comment: Could you give some more case samples of what you do and do NOT wish to match on.

Comment: added, let me know if that helps. i suppose this may be two regexps?  one to grab the number at the start, and another to grab the rest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use capturing groups for both first and rest. Try this regex:

```
^(\d+(?:,\d+)*)\s+(.*)
```

Now the group 1 is your comma separated numbers and group 2 is the rest. \s+ eats the whitespace in between. (at least 1 required).

And of course, if the regex does not match at all, then it does not start with a number or comma separated list of numbers, followed by one whitespace character or more.

Comment: why does this return 3 args in javascript?  e.g. `var s = '23,234,456 one two three'; s.match(/^(\d+(?:,\d+)*)\s+(.*)/);` returns: `
["23,234,456 one two three", "23,234,456", "one two three"]`

Comment: Element 0 is the whole match, elements after that are the substrings matched by the capturing parentheses. Read more at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_Parenthesized_Substring_Matches

Answer (score 2):

Unless I am greatly mistaken, you can simply [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on the first space.

You could also check the string against `/^[0-9,]+ /`, and if it does not match, you can skip the split in the first place.

Edit: Unfortunately, I don't think JavaScript provides an easy way to just split on the first instance of a character.

Here is a regex to match the values and put them in captured groups:

```
^(?:([0-9,]+)\s)?(.*)$
```

Comment: +1 Indeed - `split()` the string. Regex is overkill in this instance.

Comment: how would this work?  the regexp test makes sense, as does splitting to get all objects between spaces, but is there a way to make split give me the first nonspace entity and the rest? split() takes a limiter, but it seems to only stop the operation (e.g. `'23,234 one two three'.split(' ',1)` gives me `23,234` and `one`.

Comment: @mix: I discovered that when running a little test. See the edited answer.